# How to end a request.js ServerResponse stream that never ends

Tags: node.js, stream, pipe

I have this code to grab a video feed on command, but once started it never stops

```js
async function getBandonBeachesOne(req, res, next) {
  let timer = 0;
  let videoURL =
    "http://dizzyisadog.viewnetcam.com:50000/nphMotionJpeg?Resolution=640x480&Quality=Clarity";
  let videoStream = request
    .get(videoURL)
    .on("data", function (data) {
      timer++;
      if (timer > 30) {
        timer = 0;
        console.log("received " + data.length + " bytes of compressed data");
      }
    })
    .on("end", () => {
      console.log("end");
    })
    .pipe(res);

  req.on("close", () => {
    console.log("Client left");
    videoStream.end("end");
    videoStream.destroy();//data keeps comming from the request.get(videoURL)
  });
}
```

This is a request handler, it gets the video feed and pipes it to the client.  Once the client leaves, I get the `"Client left"` message, but no maktter what I try, I can't stop the `on('data')` event form firing forever

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40875559/5231665 `videoStream.abort()` Did the trick!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to this [answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40875559/5231665)
I found the solution to be
`videoStream.abort()`